# Maximising the volume of a can with respect to a given surface area

Tags: calculus, geometry

Here's how I approached this problem:

The can in question is a cylinder, let its radius be $r$ and its height $h$. Then we have that its surface area, $S$, is given by:

$S = 2\pi r^{2} + 2\pi rh = 2\pi r(r + h)$

$V = \pi r^{2}h$

Now I'm not sure how to proceed, since there are two variables. Could someone give a hint?

Comment: Your surface area is fixed. Use that equation to solve for one variable in terms of the other, and then substitute into the volume equation, and finally, optimize that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite h as $$h=\frac{S}{2\pi r}-r$$
plug this into $V$ to get
$$V=\pi r^2\left(\frac{S}{2\pi r}-r\right).$$
Now differentiating with respect to r and setting that equal to $0$ gives
$$\frac{dV}{dr}=\frac{S}{2}-2\pi r=0.$$
Therefore,
$$r=\frac{S}{4\pi}$$
and
$$h=2-\frac{S}{4\pi}.$$